# paypal redirect on successful checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to get my Paypal subscription to redirect to a custom page after a successful checkout.

Before submitting to Paypal I overload the submit handler, run my own function (to store details) and return a unique id. I want to attach that id to my return URL. (as a GET or POST var so to speak)

I have turned auto redirect "on" in my Paypal sandbox sellers preferences, but it only seems to re-direct to the URL that I HAVE to put in there.

using the `<input type="hidden" name="return" value="someurl" />` does no seem to work.

I want it this way so that I can capture the user information when entered with a "non-paid" flag, then via the IPN I can update that record with a "PAID" flag, and I want to use the unique ID to tie it all together so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden field name needs to comply with the accepted variable name required by PayPal. Does ReturnUrl (not case-sensitive) not work?

```
<input type=hidden name="RETURNURL" value="https://www.YourReturnURL.com">
```

**Note:** I have only investigated and implemented express checkout so this may not apply to your implemenation: https://cms.paypal.com/en/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted

Comment: The documented name is 'return' according to the current IPN manual.